# Using hash tables in Javascript: is an array of arrays adequate?

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashtable

I need an [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) in Javascript, i.e. to implement an associative array which maps keys (strings) to values (in my case, these are several integer arrays). I realized that this kind of approach is not commonly used, or at least I haven't found it on the web yet:

```js
var hash = ['s0'];
for (var i = 5; i >= 1; i--) {
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  hash['s'+i] = [r, r*2, r^2];
}
console.log(hash);
hash.forEach(function (v, i, a) {
  document.getElementById('foreach').innerHTML += i + ' => ' + v + '<br>';
})
for (var i = 5; i >= 1; i--) {
  var key = 's'+i;
  document.getElementById('for').innerHTML += key + ' => [' + hash[key].toString() + ']<br>';
}
```

```html
<p id="foreach">forEach (val,index):<br/></p>
<p id="for">for:<br/></p>
```

Perhaps due to the fact that the declared array seems to not be correctly mapped after I add the new values (open your console and click the `+` button, you can see the values are there even when it displays `[s1]`). The `forEach` keeps assuming the array only has one value, but if I access any of those keys directly, e.g. `hash['s3']`, the respective array is returned.

Therefore, am I doing something wrong? Should I even use this approach?

---

<sup>If objects in JSON are more appropriate for this case, what is the best way to implement something simple and similar to the example above?</sup>

Furthermore, if `key_string` is the string I want as key, `hash.push(key_string: val_array)` fails because it is not a "formal parameter". However by doing something like:

```
hash.push({'key':key_string,'value':val_array})
```

How can I access one of those arrays in the simplest way possible through its associated key?

Comment: javascript object properties act about the same as a hash table or associative array, implementing a hash table in javascript is either the wrong way to solve whatever problem you are trying to solve, or a homework question.

Comment: change var hash=['s0'] to var hash = {'s0':'first_element'}; and see what it does

Comment: Thanks @chiliNUT, but if object properties "act about the same as an hash table" and if by "homework question" you are saying this is a "trivial question", would you kindly provide a simple alternative to the hash table problem? I am using a code similar to the above and it works for my purposes, but it is not a convenient thing to not be able to use `forEach`...

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON object", by the way, there's just JSON (which is a string) and object which is an Object...

Comment: Thanks @VladimirM, I have tried the Object approach, and if you notice the small letters at the end the question, using a dynamic key (`key_string`) has not worked for me.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan by JSON object, I was referring to the notation used in the ["JS Object Notation"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).

Comment: @CPHPython ...which refers to a string value.

Comment: Alright, I get it @MikeMcCaughan. Thanks, I just rephrased it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use a JavaScript Map()?

[MDN JavaScript Reference: Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

I modified your code below to use a Map instead of an Array:

```js
var map = new Map();
for (var i = 5; i >= 1; i--) {
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  map.set('s'+i, [r, r*2, r^2]);
}
console.log(map);
map.forEach(function (v, i, m) {
  document.getElementById('foreach').innerHTML += i + ' => ' + v + '<br>';
})
for (var i = 5; i >= 1; i--) {
  var key = 's'+i;
  document.getElementById('for').innerHTML += key + ' => [' + map.get(key).toString() + ']<br>';
}
```

```html
<p id="foreach">forEach (val,index):<br/></p>
<p id="for">for:<br/></p>
```

Comment: Alright! I knew there was something I was missing! Truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's object type covers all the behavior you are looking for:

```
var obj = {};
for (var i = 5; i >= 1; i--) {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    obj['s'+i] = [r, r*2, r^2];
}
```

The cool thing about the object type in Javascript is you can access properties using the associate array-like syntax or using dot notation.

```
obj['key'] === obj.key
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, check this example in the console.

```
var hash = {'s0':' '};
for (var i = 5; i >= 1; i--) {
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  hash['s'+i] = [r, r*2, r^2];
}
```

see that hash object now contains key-value mapping

```
console.log(hash);
```

to access the object with forEach you can extract the keys of the object as an array and iterate over it:

```
Object.keys(hash).forEach(function (v, i, a) {
  console.log( i , v, hash[v] );
})
```

You may also start using such libraries as https://lodash.com/ that implement a number of common operations over collections.

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.